# Can I map a string literal to a type of types?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have a string literal type, such as

```js
type ConfigurationTypes = 'test' | 'mock'
```

and some types

```js
type MockType = { id: string }
type TestType = { code: string }
```

And I wanted to create a type that "maps" the string literal to this types, so that if `ConfigurationTypes` changes, my type `MappedConfigurationTypes` would also be required to change accordingly. Is it even possible?

```js
type MappedConfigurationTypes: {[key in ConfigurationTypes]: any} = {
  test: TestType
  mock: MockType
}
```

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mq96jm) meet your needs? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz yes it does! Please, if you could explain, I've never seen this "Extends" used like this, and well, my search was branching into higher kinded types, but this would work nicely

Comment: No worries, this excerpt has already solved the issue I had been trying to solve for the last couple of hours, thank you a lot and hope you have a nice day (or night!)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In some sense you're looking for a type-level [`satisfies` operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-9.html#the-satisfies-operator).  If you write `e satisfies T` where `e` is some expression and `T` is some type, the compiler will make sure that `e` is *assignable* to `T` without *widening* to `T`, so `e` keeps its original type but you'll get an error if is incompatible with `T`.  You want to do the same thing but replace the expression with another type. Something like

```
// this is invalid TS, don't do this:
type MappedConfigurationTypes = {
  test: testType; 
  mock: MockType
} Satisfies {[K in ConfigurationTypes]: any}
```

but there is no such `Satisfies` type operator.  Too bad.

---

Luckily we can essentially build one ourselves: instead of `T Satisfies U`, we could write `Satisfies<U, T>` (I'm making "`Satisfies U`" the syntactic unit of note, so that's why I want `Satisfies<U, T>` and not `Satisfies<T, U>`. But you can define it however you want).

Here's the definition:

```
type Satisfies<U, T extends U> = T;
```

You can see how `Satisfies<U, T>` will always evaluate to just `T`, but since `T` is [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to `U`, the compiler will complain if `T` is not compatible with `U`.

---

Let's try it:

```
type ConfigurationTypes = 'test' | 'mock';
type MockType = { id: string }
type TestType = { code: string }        

type MappedConfigurationTypes = Satisfies<{ [K in ConfigurationTypes]: any }, {
    test: TestType
    mock: MockType
}>
```

Looks good.  If you hover over `MappedConfigurationTypes` you see it is equivalent to

```
/* type MappedConfigurationTypes = {
    test: TestType;
    mock: MockType;
} */
```

On the other hand if you add another member to the `ConfigurationTypes` [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types), you'll see the desired error:

```
type ConfigurationTypes = 'test' | 'mock' | 'oops'

type MappedConfigurationTypes = Satisfies<{ [K in ConfigurationTypes]: any }, {
    test: TestType
    mock: MockType,
}> // error!
//   Property 'oops' is missing in type '{ test: TestType; mock: MockType; }' but required 
//   in type '{ test: any; mock: any; oops: any; }'.
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAyghsAlgZwGaIsgPAVQDRQAqUEAHsBAHYAmyUOAfFALxEDcAUB6JFAMIB7SugDmAVwBOCREMLhMLKAHIKyYEqgAfZQFsBAYwDWS7vKgBZA4bm9WAbyiJqALihqJiSiKgBfU70JMYBtoeyh9AWoIV3dPbz9-aHM4MEhqQWFEcSkkWXk6VngkNAxsBwBtAGlHSn4hUUlpPMhkAF1XOEoQXwI7DigBqFVgV0C1EP7BvSNXSyMJnwYOAHoAKiGzZNSIdPqsxtzKEIKoPsGhoNGgkM5z6cNZqxuOHyhV5a4uSjgdTDA4fTQADyAjAdDOgx40AyDRyMiO+UUKiCGm0SnuqOUAlByBMkwGUIsKTSMP2cOaCkK0hKmCwFWqnjqmWyTQRLXaUE63R8vXx5wuaiu43kfLuVke83keD5iygy2WJAkEgEEgAhHz5YMAArKyASUBYnEaFBQHQoZBxGobXhKBzDIXBeRsU3iixPJ2+DQAIzEwCgEggAEcxIgA9QoBqFQNGYTbQKRpyus77h0k1BsWDUyBnT4lAA6T4+IA)

Comment: You're the best!

Answer (score 0):

I did some fidgeting to the code provided by jcalz and I arrived at a slightly better solution for my problem:

```js
type MapFromLiteral<U extends string, T extends { [key in U]: any }> = T;
```

Which can be used as

```js
type MappedConfigurationTypes = MapFromLiteral<ConfigurationTypes, {
    test: TestType,
    mock: MockType
}>
```